# Creating a 3d illusion pattern

Tags: 3d, optical-illusion

I want to make a pattern to etch on a table with a laser. What I want to do is start by generating a repeating pattern and then bend it in a way that makes it look like it's going in and out of the page. Something like the background of this pic but 100% original. If you can tell me what software to use and give me the steps I'd appreciate it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a repeating pattern, then you could use the Liquify filter in Photoshop and use its Pucker tool, or you could use the Warp Transform Tool in GIMP, and in the Tool Options set it to "Shrink Area".

Here's an example made using GIMP's Warp Transform tool. The same is possible in Photoshop using the Liquify filter.

[image]

Comment: fantastic! that's exactly what i was looking for! thanx. any file type is fine, no vectoring needed. i can etch raster images. So the one last thing is figuring out how to generate a repeating pattern from scratch. Is there a tool you know for that?

Comment: @DrorSapir You can use GIMP or Photoshop to make seamless patterns. Perhaps search for some tutorials. There are some on youtube.